# Trying concurrent updates(AddToSet) to collection in mongodb and its not working correctly

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have FileAggregateReport class:

```
 public class FileAggregateReport
{        
    public Guid FileId { get; set; }

    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfSupportedEngines { get; set; }

    public int EnginesCompleted { get; set; }

    public string SHA256 { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScanDate { get; set; }

    public List<EngineReport> EngineReports { get; set; }        
}
```

and i am trying to add to the list `EngineReports` reports as update operation.

my insert report function is:(`FileAggregateReportCollection` is `IMongoCollection<FileAggregateReport>`)

```
public void InsertNewEngineReport(Guid CorrelationId, Guid FileId, EngineReport engineReport, string sha256, int numberOfSupportedEngines)
    {           
        var update = Builders<FileAggregateReport>.Update
            .Inc(report => report.EnginesCompleted, 1)
            .Set(report =>  report.CorrelationId, CorrelationId)
            .Set(report => report.FileId, FileId)
            .SetOnInsert(report => report.ScanDate, engineReport.ScanDate)
            .SetOnInsert(report => report.SHA256, sha256)
            .AddToSet( report => report.EngineReports, engineReport)
            .Set(report => report.NumberOfSupportedEngines, numberOfSupportedEngines);            

        UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

        try
        {                
            _mongoDbHelper.FileAggregateReportCollection.UpdateOne(e => e.FileId == FileId, update, options);                
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new StateRepositoryException(e.Message);
        }
    }               
}
```

when i'm doing test like this:

```
Guid cor = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid fileID = Guid.NewGuid();
EngineReport report = new EngineReport()
{
   FileId = fileID
};
_fileResultRepository.InsertNewEngineReport(cor, fileID, report, "dfsdfsdf", 15);

Task[] tasks = new Task[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      Task task = Task.Run(() => 
     _fileResultRepository.InsertNewEngineReport(cor, fileID, new EngineReport()
      {
        FileId = fileID,
        EngineType = EngineType.Clamav,
        MaliciousScore = 70,
        ScanDate = DateTime.Now,
        ShortSummary = "ATD"
      }, "dfsdfsdf", 5));
      tasks[i]=task;
  }                                                       
 Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

but in my result of this test i have in `EnginesReport` only 3 element and its need to be 6.
And sometimes i got `E11000 duplicate key error collection: FileResultAggregationRepository.FileAggregateReport index: _id_ dup key: { : BinData(3, 2A03C999127FDF4AAF293C5C086BEC66)` but i cannot reproduce this.

Comment: [This is known issue with mongodb](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322)

Comment: thanks for the link, i understand that this is known issue but i didn't got any exception when i run the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw from mongodb docs the definition of `AddToSet`=> "The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array."

I added new `Id` for `FileAggregateReport` because `FileId` was identical to all `EngineReports`, after i changed that in my test i got 6 `EngineReports` as i expected.